# How do I create collision detection with an object and part of a background?

Tags: libgdx, sprite, collision, detection

I am just starting to attempt to make my own game using java and libgdx, and the extent of my success so far has been showing the background image on screen, and spawning a little square the user controls with WASD. The background is just a solid color, with a vertical rectangle that is red inside and has black edges. I want to make it so the tiny square (player) can move anywhere within the red rectangle, but not be able to cross over the black edges (out of the rectangle). How would I go about doing this?

Since I am a complete beginner to this stuff I must ask these related questions...

Should the player be just a texture? Should the background be a texture? or a sprite?

I'm not sure the difference between the two yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommand you to read tutorials about libGDX and Box2D like this one : http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/08/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-13-Physics-with-Box2D-Part-1-A-Basic-Physics-Simulations.aspx

to answer you're questions, in short :

- a texture is an image in memory
- a sprite is a part of a texture (or the whole texture) transformed (translation, scale, rotation) to be drawn on screen.

so basically, in the view model, your player is represented by a sprite, your background is a sprite as well.
Player 1 and 2 are 2 different sprites but may reffer to the same texture (bitmap).
with box2D, in the physics model, your player will be represented as a dynamic body and your background as a static body.